# Persist Some Data Between Database Backup and Restore

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have a database in SQL Server 2008 (not R2)

A third party has the job of replacing the database regularly by restoring the data in the live environment from a .bak file made in the development environment. This leads to the destruction of any user generated data in that database. I am restricted in the live environment and cannot have two databases there.

One solution I am thinking about is to write a stored procedure that could save somehow the user generated data to some kind of local file and then once the development .bak is restored a second stored procedure could write this data back from the local file.

I'm familiar with using generate scripts that will generate a .sql file so maybe something similar to this, but it needs to be generated from a sql query that contains only the user generated data (these are specific rows of certain tables that are joined together - not the best design but it's what I have to work with).

Is it possible to generate a SQL script from a SQL query? Or is there some other kind of local file storage I could use. Something like a CSV file would be ok but I'm not aware of an easy way to automate restoring this. It will need to be restored with some very specific sql queries.

Comment: This is a pretty huge topic here. The absolute best way of handling this is with a second database. Without that you are going to be hacking this together with a machete.It really isn't very clear what your actual situation is.

Comment: Thanks Sean - yes it's a bit of a major disappointment not to get the 2nd DB I asked for - it's beyond me why I can't have it but after a year of arguing it seems I can't. Just wondering if there exists some way of doing this that I've not thought of.

Comment: Can you put your second database on another server? Then you could use the data import tool using queries.

Comment: sadly - no - the live databases have no access to anywhere else due to firewalls

Comment: So you need this data after overwriting the production database but you can't use a second database or a remote database. You could write everything to a flat file and then run a bunch of sql to import it again. This of course would require either a CLR procedure or some sort of programming logic. This sounds like a case of business requirements that need to force a change in IT policy. Good luck, this is an uphill battle.

Comment: So this is a type of sync issue. If you have promoted some features from UAT to PROD those would be brought back with the restore, but the work in progress, i.e. checked in work would be lost. Normally we would approach this using the publish feature of Visual Studio, and combination of post and pre deployment scripts, to apply necessary data and schema changes. This situation can actually help you to resolve an issues with the integration testing ;)

Comment: Could you have a second database on a different DBMS?